# Swift tableview, reloadRows after SwipeAction, unable to swipe again on the same row

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a tableView with swipeActions, 
and these action call `tableView.reloadRows` to update my table.

I noticed that i cannot swipe again a just updated row after action.

the problem was this cell keep stats of that SwipeActions panel is shown.
I think a simple method that "Swipe back" this cell back will resolve my issue, but i dont find any.

(i dont want to reload whole tableView)

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
    trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
     let removeAction = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil, handler: { _, _, _ in
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
//            self.items.remove(at: indexPath.row)
//            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
     })
     removeAction.image = UIImage(named: "ic_garbage")!.scaleImageToFitSize(size: CGSize(width: 32.0, height: 32.0))
     removeAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
     let actionModify = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: nil, handler: { _, _, _ in
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
//            self.changeQty(indexPath)
     })
     actionModify.image = UIImage(named: "ic_exchange")!.scaleImageToFitSize(size: CGSize(width: 32.0, height: 32.0))
     actionModify.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange

     let toReturn = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [removeAction, actionModify])
     toReturn.performsFirstActionWithFullSwipe = false
     return toReturn
}
```

Comment: Can you post your data source logic?

Comment: try func reloadSections(_ sections: IndexSet, with animation: UITableView.RowAnimation)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to be calling the completion handler. Your actions should be defined like this...

```
let action = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Hello") { (action, view, completion) in
    self.doSomething()
    completion(true)
}
```